# Share internet from PC and Router

Tags: networking, windows-7, router, internet-connection

I have windows 7 on my PC, and connect internet through brodband flash, and I connected my PC with Wireles lite N Router(TP-link). my question is: how can share internet on the pc through this router to other laptops and smartphones?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way I see this being done is the following:

1. Configure your wired ethernet connection with a static address and subnet with the gateway set to the broadband adapter address and the DNS set to the broadband adapter's DNS servers.
2. Connect the router to the PC via the WAN port and configure the WAN with a static address on th same subnet as the PC with the gateway set to the IP address of the PC and the DNS servers set to those of the broadband adapter.
3. Configure the wireless router to provide DHCP to your wireless devices.

This should theoretically allow your traffic from the wireless devices to go through the router to the PC and out over the broadband card.

For example (using Google's DNS servers):

```
PC:
    IP: 10.11.12.1
    Subnet: 255.255.255.0
    Gateway: YOUR BROADBAND CARD IP
    DNS1: 8.8.8.8
    DNS2: 4.4.4.4

Router Wan:
    IP: 10.11.12.2
    Subnet: 255.255.255.0
    Gateway: 10.11.12.1
    DNS1: 8.8.8.8
    DNS2: 4.4.4.4
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Many thanks,
Actually I am not good in network configurations, but I will do my best to follow these steps : fist regarding to the first point do you mean to configure local area connection  properties like iP versin 4?